# A distance metric based on tree paths

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology, trees

Let $T$ be a connected and acyclic 1-dimensional subset of the plane (a union of curves). For every two points $ְA,B$ in $T$, there is a unique simple path between $A$ and $B$ along the lines of $T$. As an example, here:

[image]

T is represented by the black solid lines, and the unique path between A and B is represented by the green dotted line.

Therefore, there is a well-defined distance $d(A,B)$, which is the shortest distance that we have to travel, along lines of $T$, to get from $A$ to $B$. This $d$ is metric, and I am studying its properties. Is there a term that describes this metric, by which I can search for such properties? I tried "tree distance" but it lead to entirely different concepts.

Comment: You can take this curve and equate it to some subset of the real line then call the metric euclidean distance.

Comment: @justaguy but it is a tree - it may have "junctions". Something like this: https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/11/33/tree-created-with-wireframe-and-lines-connected-vector-24291133.jpg

Comment: As long as you are looking at a pair of points you can ignore junctions and do what I stated above. Otherwise I will look into if there is a general term for such a metric.

Comment: I spent some happy days in 1976 writing notes on metric spaces with the property that, for all $a > 0,$ every set of diameter $a$ is contained in a ball of radius $a/2.$ I seem to remember proving that, probably with some additional condition I've forgotten (completeness?), every such space was given by such a metric on some sort of tree. I certainly concluded that such spaces had a property I later learned characterises [median graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_graph). Unfortunately I destroyed all my mathematics notes, so apart from the Wikipedia reference I can't be of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of space you're looking at is a real tree:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree

Comment: Thanks! This indeed looks very related. But I could not understand from that article: is there a proof that any connected and acyclic collection of curves in the plane (e.g. the one I plotted in the question) is indeed a real tree?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "curve". If each path (such as the green path) is rectifiable then it's true and pretty easy to prove that path length defines an $\mathbb R$-tree structure on the space. In your question, where you wrote "there is a well-defined distance $d(A,B)$", that's more or less equivalent to the rectifiability assumption. However, that property can fail for continuous curves in general, in which case no distance is defined, so no metric is defined, and without a metric it doesn't even make sense to assert that it's an $\mathbb R$-tree.

Answer (score 0):

In general given a path connected metric space $X$, we can define it's [intrinsic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) to be

$$d_I(x, y) = \inf_{p \text{ a path from $x$ to $y$}} \ell(p) $$
where $\ell(p)$ denotes the length of the path.

Comment: How is it related to a tree?